# Php If Condition in Array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to built an if condition in my array currently looks like this but does not work.

```
protected $menuItems = [
    'items' => [
        [
            'title' => 'test',
        ],
        $this->hasma() ? [
            'title' => 'Ma',
        ] : null,
    ],
]
```

Basically hasma returns true or false, if it is true it shall add the above and if it is false I shall return (add) nothing.

Comment: how would you manage this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
protected $menuItems = [
    'items' => [
        [
            'title' => 'test',
        ]
    ]
]

if($this->hasma())
    $menuItems['items'][] = ['title' => 'Ma']
```

When looking the code, i noticed that you used the keyword "protected" which involve that you're hardcoded the value of your class property in the declaration.
Instead, you should initialize all your propertys in contructor method.
The code would look like this :

```
 <?php

class A
{

    protected $menuItems;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->menuItems = [
            'items' => [
                ['title' => 'test']
            ]
        ];

        if($this->hasma())
            $menuItems['items'][] = ['title' => 'Ma'];
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Place the `if(...)` condition inside the `__construct()` magic method so it'll be executed when creating the instance.

Comment: i think it is a best practice

Comment: I get this now Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: i tested and updated the code so that its error free and working
you can copy paste if mind free now ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Build that array inside your constructor. If you build an array in that way it would be call the hasma method while the object is instaziated. 
So do something like this:

```
function __construct(){
  $this->menuItems=[['title' =>'test']];
  if($this->hasma())
   $this->menuItems[1]=['title'=>'Ma'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use **$this** when you are declaring your class properties. You can do the following however:

```
class Test {

    protected $menuItems;

    function hasma() {
        return true;
    }

    function __construct() {
        $this->menuItems = [
        'items' => [
                [
                    'title' => 'test',
                ],
                $this->hasma() ? [
                    'title' => 'Ma',
                ] : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    function getMenu() {
        return $this->menuItems;
    }
}

$test = new Test();

print_r($test->getMenu());
```

Comment: I do get this message Trying to get property of non-object